# Proper way to change HtmlNode value in document using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html, parsing, xpath, html-agility-pack

I want to change node's inner html in the document but the following code doesn't work unfortunately:

```
HtmlNodeCollection sourceTables = _sourceDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table");
sourceTables[0].InnerHtml = "lalala";
```

The node's inner html changes properly, but it **doesn't affect document html**.

And this method doesn't work, because the node cannot be found:

```
_sourceDoc.DocumentNode.ReplaceChild(HtmlNode.CreateNode("<test></test>"), sourceTables[0]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a notable bug in the library (http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/workitem/32959). It has been fixed very recently, at least in the source (it's not in the 1.4.6 release). You can do a get latest and recompile.